# Error with (fern-wifi-cracker)

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless

When I enter the command

sudo dpkg -i Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb

this error come up

```
mohamed@mohamed-K55A:~/Downloads/aircrack-ng-1.2-beta2$ cd /home/mohamed/Desktop
mohamed@mohamed-K55A:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package fern-wifi-cracker.
(Reading database ... 211283 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fern-wifi-cracker (from Fern-Wifi-Cracker_1.6_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fern-wifi-cracker:
 fern-wifi-cracker depends on aircrack-ng; however:
  Package aircrack-ng is not installed.
 fern-wifi-cracker depends on python-scapy (>= 2.0); however:
  Package python-scapy is not installed.
dpkg: error processing fern-wifi-cracker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fern-wifi-cracker
```

any solution

and when i enter the command `sudo apt-get -f install`
 this is come up
`mohamed@mohamed-K55A:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fern-wifi-cracker
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3514 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 215040 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fern-wifi-cracker ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...`
and i'm using (ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Comment: Have you installed `aircrack-ng` and `python-scapy` yet? The error message seems very clear to me. Running `dpkg -i foo.deb` will not automatically resolve the dependencies of `foo.deb`. You will need to install them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been found the SOL. type in terminal:

```
user@user2343:~$svn checkout http://fern-wifi-cracker.googlecode.com/svn/Fern-Wifi-Cracker/
user@user2343:~$cd /home/user/Fern-Wifi-Cracker
user@user2343:~/Fern-Wifi-Cracker$ sudo python execute.py
```

but you should must install all files that fern-wifi-cracker that need it

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will hopefully clear any issues with previous updates or installs.

Comment: not working at all

Comment: do you get any message when you type this command in?

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?